# count cookies in python

Tags: python

I am struggling with python ,I want to Write a Python script that creates a cookie and Counts how many times the cookie is called during a session
I just have tried as per below:

```
import Cookie
import os
if os.environ.has_key('HTTP_COOKIE'):
    cookie=SimpleCookie(os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])
cookie=SimpleCookie()
for key in initialvalues.keys():
    if not cookie.has_key(key):
        cookie[key]=intialvalues[key]
        return cookie
        if __name__=='__main__':
            c=getCookie({'counter':0})
            c['counter']=int(c['counter'].value)+1
            print c
```

But I know it is wrong, can someone help me to write down the script?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you call cookie during seassion, and how does this code works?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question.  What I believe you want to do is request some webpage and count how many times your cookie was found?  You can gather cookies using a CookieJar:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

url = "http://example.com/cookies"
form_data = {'username': '', 'password': '' }

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
# data returned from this pages contains redirection
resp = opener.open(url, form_data)

print resp.read()

for cookie in jar:
  # Look for your cookie
```